# ¿como bloquear las capturas de pantalla en dispositivos moviles a una pagina web?

Tags: javascript, android

Necesito bloquear las capturas de pantalla en moviles(Android, IOS) para una pagina web, la cual tiene como objetivo realizar examenes en linea.

el siguiente codigo(que encontré en otro foro) en javascript realiza el bloqueo de printscreen y tecla ctrl pero solo para PC, quiero saber si es posible adaptarlo para dispositivos moviles android y iOS:

```
<script>
function copyToClipboard() {
  // Create a "hidden" input
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  // Assign it the value of the specified element
  aux.setAttribute("value", "Você não pode mais dar printscreen. Isto faz parte da nova medida de segurança do sistema.");
  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  // Highlight its content
  aux.select();
  // Copy the highlighted text
  document.execCommand("copy");
  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
  alert("Print screen desabilitado.");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 44 || e.keyCode == 17){
            copyToClipboard();
        }


    }); 
    $(window).focus(function() {
        $("body").show();
    }).blur(function() {
        $("body").hide();
    });}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor lee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007905/is-there-any-way-to-disable-the-screenshot-to-the-particular-website-image-can

Comment: Actualmente no es posible prevenir capturas de pantalla desde dispositivos móviles.

Comment: Más información (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android

Comment: Debes especificar si es una pagina web en tu dispositivo o si esta pagina se encuentra dentro de una aplicacion.

Comment: es para una pagina web en mi dispositivo.